# AWS - Missing CSV file name while downloading file from backend using API Gateway

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, csv, aws-api-gateway

I am having a use-case where I need to download the CSV file from back-end application.

For this I am using AWS API Gateway and Elastic Beanstalk (running in private subnet).

I am successfully able to do the required API Gateway and beanstalk integration and also my frontend application (running in Angular 8) is able to get the CSV file.

While executing the download request, the backend Django application is providing a filename, for ex- `my-data-list.csv` to the download CSV file.

However, when the request goes to Django application through API Gateway, I am able to get the data in CSV file, but I am not able to get the name of CSV file that I can use it for downloading purpose.

My question is, what are the parameter settings required to get the filename as well along with the complete CSV file?

Thanks in Advance.

Avinash

Answer (score 0):

In API Gateway I think for GET and POST requests require to use the "Use Proxy Integration" option for the binary data transactions.

I have changed the integration type and used "Use Proxy Integration" option and able to receive the file name.

Go to API Gateway -> Resource -> Method (GET / POST) -> Integration Request and select option "Use Proxy Integration".